# Storyboard - How to segue to a SplitViewController from a Viewcontroller in navigation based application

Tags: storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I have a navigation controller based iPad application. I am using storyboards for the app design. From one of the ViewControllers in the Navigation stack, I need to segue to a screen showing splitviewcontroller. how to I go about that ?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing right now?

Answer (score 1):

A `UISplitViewController` must always be the first/main view controller you use. You can't use it from a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController` or similar.

Comment: What is the best practice technique for when you need some other screen to display before the SplitViewController - for example, a login screen or main menu?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and I solved it by implementing a custom segue.

```
@implementation LoginSegue
- (void) perform {
    NSLog(@"Do the segue you way");
    UIViewController *src = self.sourceViewController;
    UIWindow *window = src.view.window;
    [window addSubview:[self.destinationViewController view]];
    window.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController;
}
@end
```

This seems to have worked for me.  I hope this is an acceptable solution when I submit the code to apple.

Comment: In the prototype we have developed, we started with a simple view, and replaced the main window with the UISplitViewController when the login is successful using a custom Segue.  I have provided the implementation for the same in my other comment.  A segue object gives to access to both source and destination.  As part of the seque I am replacing the view the main window with the view from the UISplitViewController.